# gsutil says it cannot find python

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, gsutil

I installed the cloud SDK. The path variable is updated to the location of the sdk
I have python 2.7 and python 3.8 installed on the machine. Python 2.7 is installed at
C;\Python27\python.exe
Now when I run the gsutil I get an error

```
C:\Windows\system32>gsutil
ERROR: (gsutil) "C:\Python27\python.exe": command not found
```

Comment: The SDK includes its own version of Python. Have you modified the PATH environment variable? The easiest solution is to uninstall the SDK and then reinstall.

Comment: Try to reinstall gcloud SDK

Comment: I tried reinstalling and I have path to python.exe in PATH variable too, but it didnt help

Comment: Can you verify the version of Python by running 'c:\python27\python.exe --version'? Also, which version of the SDK are you installing?